# What are some issues with setting up a new AD Forest with a DNS name under an existing AD Forest?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Active Directory Forest A exists as domain.net, with child domains of nam.domain.net, eur.domain.net etc.

Forest B needs to be raised. What issues could arise from setting this up as msg.domain.net?

No Microsoft DNS servers involved.
A single DNS infrastructure would support all forests.
Two-way trust between forests.
Security or operational considerations would be most important.

Comment: Organizational or structural problems for once. Forests are supposed to be independant. So if you have siblings you maybe will remember what problems arise when you share a coloring book with your sibling. If you colored something yellow and your bigger siblings then decised to color the same spot black there is nothing you can do. The yellow color is still there, you just don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done without error. Active Directory relies on DNS heavily for finding services within the domain and forest. With a single DNS infrastructure the srv records for both AD forests would reside in the same domain.net DNS zone.  DC's would read the forest-wide srv records, reading the details of all Domain Controllers in both forests, and attempt AD DS replication for schema, and the forest-wide partitions. Although there's a trust in place, the aforementioned partitions are unique to the individual forest, and so would either bastardise themselves or more probably refuse to replicate, resulting in errors in both forests.